# python load instance fast

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

I have a class containing data that I'd like to save and load. 
I also would like my environment (PyCharm) to recognize the object y=MyClass.load('C:\some path.pkl') as a MyClass instance and autocomplete accordingly in future lines.

I have 2 functions within the class, 'load' recognizes y, while 'fast_load' doesn't. but the latter is much faster (up to 10 times) if the loaded instance contains a lot of data.
Is there a way to control the loaded object instance without copying the entire data to a new class instance?

here's the relevant part of my code:

```
import cPickle as pickle
from copy import deepcopy

def save(obj, filename):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as output:
        pickle.dump(obj, output, -1)


def load(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as input_:
        return pickle.load(input_)

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, save_path,run_time=0):
        ...

    def save(self, path=None):
        save(self, path)

    @staticmethod
    def load(path):
        ad_obj = MyClass('', 0)
        ad_obj.__dict__ = deepcopy(load(path).__dict__)
        return ad_obj

    @staticmethod
    def fast_load(path):
        return load(path)
```

thanks

Comment: This seems like two separate questions. Or maybe not. Is it just about getting PyCharm to understand what `fast_load()` returns?

Comment: Yes. the load() function is supposed to be the solution but it's too slow.

Answer (score 0):

With Python 3, this would be easy. You'd just add a return type annotation to the `load` function like this (noting that you would have to define `load` after `MyClass`):

```
def load(filename): -> MyClass
    ...
```

With Python 2, you have to do something more convoluted by adding args to the docstring as noted in [the PyCharm docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html).

Personally, I like [Google style docstrings](http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html):

```
def load(filename):
    """Load something.

    Returns:
        MyClass

    """
```

Comment: that solved it. Thanks! 
I tried '# type: (str) -> MyClass' initially but that doesn't work. I wonder why.

Comment: @denisfenderbottom No problem. Feel free to upvote :)